# How to define constants at compilation time

Tags: go

I know that I can use compiler flag in Go for variables, but how to do it for constants?

I would like to set some constants, like database sets, at compile time like that:

```
package db_info

var Deploy string

const DbType   = "mysql"
const DbUser   = "my_user"
const Db       = "my_db"
const DbPort   = "3306"

if Deploy == "staging" {
    const DbPassword = "my_pwd_stg"
    const DbHost     = "db.url.com"
} else if Deploy == "production" {
    const DbPassword = "my_pwd_prd"
    const DbHost     = "db.url.com"
} else {
    const DbPassword = "pwd"
    const DbHost     = "127.0.0.1"
}
```

How to do it in correctly? Like that I got:

```
syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that. It would break the scoping rules. You would expect the constants to be globally visible but they are defined within a block.

---

I would just pass those values as program parameters or environment variables.

---

On the other hand, as you mentioned, you can modify string variables at the compilation time. Use `-ldflags` to do it.

```
go run -ldflags="-X main.who=Something" hello.go
```

in

```
package main

import "fmt"

var who = "World"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s.\n", who)
}
```

See https://blog.cloudflare.com/setting-go-variables-at-compile-time/

Comment: That's (obviously) compile-time, not run-time.  But maybe that's what the OP wants, since they're talking about compiler flags.

Comment: It's not yet, I need it as constant, so I don't need to call a function everytime.

I have a lot of configuration (about 200 constants) that change accordanally the environment, so I need something that I can pass as parameter (only one) during compilation time, and with an IF statement in my code, outside a function, I can setup correctly each constant.